# Flat document / Document with flattened field performance comparison in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We are migrating performance data (a measurement of some physical quantity like disk capacity, network throughput ...) to a brand new Elasticserch instance. To design our indices, we face two different approaches and I would like to know the difference in performance between both. We have something like 800 billions measurements to store and search through.

First we could have a flat document that represents a single measurement such as for 3 measurements we have 3 documents

```
{
    "timestamp": date,
    "an_id": integer,
    "another_id": integer,
    "metric_id": "a_metric",
    "metric_value": scaled_float
},
{
    "timestamp": date,
    "an_id": integer,
    "another_id": integer,
    "metric_id": "another_metric",
    "metric_value": scaled_float
},
{
    "timestamp": date,
    "an_id": integer,
    "another_id": integer,
    "metric_id": "a_third_metric",
    "metric_value": scaled_float
}
```

Or we could store several measurements into a single document such as

```
{
    "timestamp": date,
    "an_id": integer,
    "another_id": integer,
    "metrics" : {
        "a_metric": "value",
        "another_metric": "value",
        "a_third_metric": "value"
    }
}
```

with `metrics` a [flattened field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html).

What are the impact regarding query performances ? Regarding any other dimension like storage ?
What are the possible trade-offs we need to accept using one solution or the other ? Such as the limited search functionality using the flattened data type.

Comment: Are you able to create desired dashboard/queries with both approaches? Based on my experience you will have a quite significant problems with one approach and that will determine your data model and this opinion based question won't be valid.

Comment: How can difference in search performance be an opinion ?
If I am ever able to have measures I will share them and answer my own question. Unfortunately, that is not the case for now.

Comment: "What would be the pros and cons of both approaches ?" is definetely opinion based formulation. Question about performance is valid.

Comment: If you asking only about performance then this question is duplicate, so it should be also closed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483099/what-are-the-performance-drawbacks-of-flat-documents-vs-nested-ones

Comment: Unfortunately, the other stackoverflow question you are pointing at does not answer this question: in February 2016 the flattened data type did not exist. It was introduced with the 7.3 version at the end of July 2019 https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-7-3-0-released . The issue here is not about flat documents vs nested ones, it is about the impact of using the flattened data type to group several flat documents in a single one. I will make this more clear in the question.

Comment: By pros and cons I was thinking about possible trade-offs since the answer may not be straightforward but dependent on other factors of some kind. I make that clear too.

Comment: I have removed Grafana references from the question, because this is pure ES topic. (BTW I bet you will have to stick to flat structure regardless of outcome from this question - Grafana has a problem with nested aggregtion https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4693 - so that is the main point of my first question "Are you able to create desired dashboard/queries with both approaches?")

Comment: No, for non-technical reasons I am not able to make the measurements myself :-( . That's why I hoped I could find someone who would have already faced this issue and could share his or her experience.

Comment: I would start dockerized es, create one index for each case, insert some data with expected time granularity and tested query performance with siege/ab/k6/... for each case.